# Node.js build ./configure options explanation

Tags: node.js

Is there any resource (documentation) on what the various `./configure` options for building Node.js from source do? For instance, what might `./configure --debug` vs `./configure --gdb` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, inside the [file itself](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/configure).

Answer (score 0):

```
./configure --help
```

This can print all options and explanations.